# x11vnc wish to not have local display updated

Tags: vnc

I have a difficult user that wants to connect via vnc to control her linux workstation while remote. However, she has an 'issue' where she does not want the workstation display to show her activity (updates, mouse moves ,etc). I currently have x11vnc configured for her and am curious if this is an option or not. Apparently turning off the monitor is not an acceptable solution in this case.

Perhaps there is another solution that will allow this instead of x11vnc?

Comment: If you don't want to connect to the console display, then x11vnc is not what you want.  Instead use one of the several other VNC servers that do not do this.  `tightvncserver` works.  Or just show them how to SSH and use X11 forwarding.